# AngularJS: Data Binding Isn't Working As Expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 App which is an AngularJS SPA (so I don't think SharePoint is an issue).

In the Default.aspx page, I am referencing all pertinent scripts:

```
    <!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ANGULARJS APPLICATION FILES -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../App/App.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../App/Controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../App/Services/SharePointJSOMService.js"></script>
```

And here is my template:

```
<div data-ng-app="appITI">
    <div data-ng-controller="MainController">
        <div id="header" class="clr-darkblue">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="../Images/head_logo.gif">
        </a>
        <span class="sp_controls" data-ng-cloak="">
            Welcome {{currentUser.Title}}
            &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a id="btnPreferences" data-ng-click="prefs = true">My Settings</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Role: {{currentUser.Role}}
            &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#">Logout</a>
        </span>
        </div> <!-- /#header -->
    </div> <!-- /mainController -->
</div> <!-- /ANGULAR APP -->
```

As you can see I am using ng-cloak but I have also tried ng-bind.

here is App.js

```
var appITI = angular.module('appITI', ['ui.bootstrap']);

var hostweburl;
var appweburl;
var currentUser;

$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runMyCode, "SP.js");
    function runMyCode(){} // end runMyCode fn
}); // end Document.Ready
```

and the controller:

```
(function(){
    var MainController = function($scope, SharePointJSOMService){
        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runMyCode, "SP.js");
        function runMyCode(){

        //get currentUser
        $.when(SharePointJSOMService.getCurrentUser())
        .done(function(jsonObject){
            currentUser = jsonObject.d;
            $scope.currentUser = currentUser;
            $scope.currentUser.Role = "RSC";
            console.dir($scope);
        }).fail(function(err){ console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); });

        } // end runMyCode fn
    }; // end MainController

    MainController.$inject = ['$scope', 'SharePointJSOMService'];

    angular.module('appITI').controller('MainController', MainController);
})();
```

Lastly, here is the service:

```
appITI.service('SharePointJSOMService', function($q, $http){
    this.getCurrentUser = function(){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
        hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
        appweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPAppWebUrl"]);

        var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
        var restQueryUrl = appweburl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";

        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: restQueryUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
                deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data.body));
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                deferred.reject(JSON.stringify(xhr));
            }
        });
        return deferred;
    }; // /getCurrentUser fn
});
```

According to everything I have read and studied, this should work. In the console.dir, everything is shown for currentUser:

```
{
       [functions]: ,
       $$asyncQueue: [ ],
       $$childHead: null,
       $$childTail: null,
       $$destroyed: false,
       $$isolateBindings: { },
       $$listenerCount: { },
       $$listeners: { },
       $$nextSibling: null,
       $$phase: null,
       $$postDigestQueue: [ ],
       $$prevSibling: null,
       $$watchers: [ ],
       $id: "003",
       $parent: { },
       $root: { },
       currentUser: {
          [functions]: ,
          __metadata: { },
          Email: "my.name@company.mail.onmicrosoft.com",
          Groups: { },
          Id: 9,
          IsHiddenInUI: false,
          IsSiteAdmin: false,
          LoginName: "i:0#.f|membership|my.name@corporate.com",
          PrincipalType: 1,
          Role: "RSC",
          Title: "Name, My (My Title)",
          UserId: { }
       },
       this: { }
    }
```

Comment: You should not mix `$.when()` with Angular.js. Angular is designed to remove the need for jQuery asynchronicity.

Comment: I am following the coding of a Senior Product Marketing Manager at Microsoft and it's the best I know at this point. I hope to learn Angular and SharePoint better very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `$.when` jQuery's promise implementation you will need to notify angular that something in the `$scope` needs updated.

At the end of this logic, call `$scope.$apply()`:

```
$.when(SharePointJSOMService.getCurrentUser())
    .done(function(jsonObject){
        currentUser = jsonObject.d;
        $scope.currentUser = currentUser;
        $scope.currentUser.Role = "RSC";
        console.dir($scope);
        $scope.$apply(); // <-- tell angular to update the scope and refresh the UI
    }).fail(function(err){ console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); });
```

Note: this is only needed when you are referencing something outside of `angular-land`

Comment: Agreed, that is the ideal solution, but there are times where existing logic and code must be re-used, and this solves the issue the OP is attempting to resolve.

Comment: Yes, I was too hasty in my assessment.  Angular can be easily incorporated into existing legacy code that is using other frameworks.  My comment was meant to say, if you are creating an Angular project from scratch, 99.9% of the time there is no reason to need jQuery (Angular includes its own version of jqlite).  New Angular developers need to think in a declarative manner to really "get" Angular.

Comment: added $scope.apply() exactly where you suggested and got "JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'. NEVER MIND -- I was still in debugger. I quit that and F5 and it works perfectly. Thanks!!!

Comment: the method name is `$apply` not `apply`

Comment: It should be added that as long as you mix jQuery and Angular in this way, you will constantly need `$scope.$apply()` and various other hacks. Avoid it!